# React native router flux to child component

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-router-flux

#### Version

Tell us which versions you are using:

- react-native-router-flux 4.0.0-beta.22
- react-native SDK 28

I have structure router.

```
const scenes2 = Actions.create(
      <Stack key="root" tabs={true} tabBarPosition={'bottom'} hideNavBar>
        <Stack key="home" hideNavBar={true} component={Home} type={ActionConst.REPLACE} title="Home" titleStyle={styles.menutab} initial={true} icon={TabIcon} image={require('@images/icon-bag.png')}>
          <Scene key="postDetails" component={PostDetails} title="Post" />
        </Stack>
        <Stack key="video" hideNavBar={true} component={Video} title="Video" icon={TabIcon} image={require('@images/icon-bag.png')}>
          <Scene key="videoDetails" component={VideoDetails} title="VideoDetails" />
        </Stack>
        <Stack key="persija" hideNavBar={true} component={Home} title="Persija" icon={TabIcon} image={require('@images/icon-bag.png')}>

        </Stack>
        <Stack key="shop" hideNavBar={true} component={Product} title="Shop" icon={TabIcon} image={require('@images/icon-bag.png')}>

        </Stack>
        <Stack key="profile" hideNavBar={true} component={Profile} title="Profile" icon={TabIcon} image={require('@images/icon-bag.png')}>

        </Stack>
      </Stack>
    );
```

And button on press.

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
    Actions.postDetails.bind(this, {post: post});
}}
style={news.bannerText}>
<Text style={news.bannerTitle}>{postTitle}</Text>
<Text style={news.bannerDate}><TimeAgo time={post.date}/></Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Get error Undefinded is not a object (evluating _reactNativeRouterFlux.Actions.postDetails.bind()

Answer (score 0):

Wellcome to SO. Actual code for `onPress` is as below:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
    Actions.postDetails({post: post});
}}
style={news.bannerText}>
<Text style={news.bannerTitle}>{postTitle}</Text>
<Text style={news.bannerDate}><TimeAgo time={post.date}/></Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Here when you are using `Actions.fileKey()` then you don't need to bind that just pass parameters simple way. For your furthur knowledge about `binding` a function please refer [this](https://medium.com/shoutem/react-to-bind-or-not-to-bind-7bf58327e22a) link and for `Actions/router-flux` please refer [this](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux#readme) link

Hope it will help.